# Upserting with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

I'm looking for a way to make my code more elegant. I want to either create an entry or update an existing one based on whether an "id" variable is empty or not. Currently my code looks like this:

```
    if(data.id == '')
        dbo.collection('parkings').insert(entry, refresh_parkings);     
    else
        dbo.collection('parkings').update({ '_id' : data.id }, entry, refresh_parkings);
```

I'm trying to merge this into one line using the *upsert* parameter. I've tried quite a few things but it doesn't work and the entry is always updated, there's no new entry created.

```
// First attempt
dbo.collection('parkings').update({ '_id' : data.id }, entry, {upsert: true}, refresh_parkings);

// Second attempt
 if(data.id != '')
   var id = {'_id': data.id};
 else
   var id = {};

dbo.collection('parkings').update(id, entry, {upsert: true}, refresh_parkings);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mongodb documentation, the upsert works as described:

> upsert: true creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria.

Here, if the query is empty `{}`, then it will match all documents. Then it update the first matching document.

SO you have to use a query that will not match any documents you have to be sure it will insert a new one. Be careful, if you use `{_id: ''}` or `{_id: 'undefined'}`, cause no document is supposed to have such an id, it won't work as expected: it will insert a new document with the specified _id as value. Be sure to use another attribute to create the query.

Try this then:

```
if(data.id != '')
   var id = {'_id': data.id};
else
  var id = {'unexistingAttribute': 'anyValue'};

dbo.collection('parkings').update(id, entry, {upsert: true}, refresh_parkings);
```

It should then create a new document AND generate a correct new _id, since no document should match the query provided.